# Return a new object with the given key and its value flipped

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

As the title says, I am trying to return a new object with the given key and its value flipped and leave all the other key/value pairs unchanged.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function swapKeyAndValue(obj, key) {
  
  const result = [];
  for (const property in obj) {result.push(obj); }
  return result;
}

var instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };

console.log(
  swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name'),
  swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'job')
  );
```

The problem is I am still learning the ins and outs of javascript, and I am not sure how to get this object to stop returning as an array, and also meet the requirements from the title.

Here is an example of what I am looking to return:

```
var instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };

swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name');
// {Elie: 'name', job: "Instructor"}

swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'job');
// {name: "Elie", Instructor: 'job'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a loop here. Instead, grab the value of the current key using bracket notation, then set the new key (which is the value) and set the new value to the key passed through. You'll then need to delete the old key which you passed through from the object like so:

```js
function swapKeyAndValue({...obj}, key) { // {...obj} will copy the object (so it doesn't change the object passed through directly)
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // check if key is in the object
    const new_key = obj[key]; // grab value
    obj[new_key] = key;
    delete obj[key];
  }

  return obj;
}

const instructor = {
  name: 'Elie',
  job: 'Instructor'
};

console.log(
  swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name'),
  swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'job')
);
```

Here is a different a less efficient approach but allows you to keep key-value order using `Object.fromEntries()`, `Object.entries()` and `.map()`:

```js
const swapKeyAndValue = (obj, key) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => k===key ? [v, k] : [k, v]));

const instructor = {
  name: 'Elie',
  job: 'Instructor'
};

console.log(
  swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name'),
  swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'job')
);
```

Comment: that makes sense! Thank you

Comment: @CodyWirth no worries

Answer (score 1):

This one works!

```
function swapKeyAndValue (obj, key) {
const newObj = {};
for (let keys in obj) {
if (keys === key) {
  newObj [obj[keys]] = key;
}
if (keys !== key) {
  newObj[keys] = obj[keys];
}
}
return newObj;

}
var instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };
swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name');
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please do add some more details to the answer, as to what this code snippet would do to help the person asking the question or anyone in the future reading the question and answer to get a clear picture :)

Answer (score 0):

You created a function which creates a new array,

but as I understand you want to change the specific object structure

so this code is the way to do so:

```js
function swapKeyAndValue(obj, key) {
  value = obj[key]
  if (value){
    obj[value]=key
    delete obj[key]
  }
}

var instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };

 swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name')
console.log(instructor);
 swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'Elie')
console.log(instructor);
 swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name')
console.log(instructor);
```

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

actually what you want is really easy to achieve using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function swapKeyAndValue(obj, key) {
  const reducer = (accum, ck) => {  // ck is the current key
    if (ck === key) {          // if ck is the key that we want to swap, we enter.
      const val = obj[ck];     // take the value to a var
      accum[val] = key;       // then we swap it
    } else {
      accum[ck] = obj[ck];    // we dont swap anything...
    }
    return accum;             // we return our partially build obj
  }
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(reducer, {});
}

var instructor = {
  name: 'Elie',
  job: 'Instructor'
};

console.log(
  swapKeyAndValue2(instructor, 'name'),
  swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'job')
);
```

the problem in your code is that you are building an `Array` and then expect it not to be one.

```
function swapKeyAndValue(obj, key) {

  const result = [];  // <---- you define an array, therefore if you return this, it will be an array
  for (const property in obj) {result.push(obj); }
  return result;
}
```

for your function to work you can do a similar approach as the `reduce` that I put above

```
function swapKeyAndValue2(obj, key) {
  const result = {};
  for (const property in obj) {
    if (property === key) {
      // we swap
      const val = obj[property];
      result[val] = property;
    } else {
      // we dont swap
      result[property] = obj[property];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple way to solve this problem using a For Loop & 2 If Statements!

```
function swapKeyAndValue(obj, swappedKey){
  var result = {};
  for(var key in obj){
  if(key === swappedKey){
    result[obj[key]] = swappedKey;
  }
    if(key !== swappedKey){
    result[key] = obj[key];
  }
}
return result;
```

}